# How to disable lex-web-ui microphone?

Tags: amazon-lex

I followed this tutorial in setting up lex bot: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/deploy-a-web-ui-for-your-chatbot/
How do I disable the microphone

I've tried modifying the lex-web-ui.js file but it keeps reverting to original versions. (I've updated the version in S3 stack)

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

1. In lex-web-ui.loader.min.js remove ,a.setAttribute("allow","microphone"). When updated, set public read only access.
2. Ensure that the code refers to updated file. In broswer script, add  above where the chatbot is loaded.